# I have a log file with different columns and from that i need only two columns

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I have a big log file from that I need only two columns. Below is a single line from the log file:

`[2017-05-02 13:02:25,986] [AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-10239] SID0003457|10.22.165.22|13|16|FAILED|500||<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Header><ns1:SessionType xmlns:ns1="http://tough.example.com/webservices">STATELESS</ns1:SessionType><ns2:UsernameToken xmlns:ns2="http://tough.example.com/webservices">ocore-intg_w
w@example.com</ns2:UsernameToken><ns3:PasswordText xmlns:ns3="http://tough.example.com/webservices">UdontsoiuN</ns3:PasswordText></S:Header><S:Body><getExternalPortalUserElement xmlns="http://ws.web.
tough1.tough.example.com/"><emailAddress>park.phannon23@example.com</emailAddress></getExternalPortalUserElement></S:Body></S:Envelope>|{http://ws.web.tough1.tough.example.com/}getExternalPortalUserElement|<n
s1:Header xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><ns1:SessionType xmlns:ns1="http://tough.example.com/webservices">STATELESS</ns1:SessionType><ns2:UsernameToken xmlns:ns2="http://tough.example.com/webservices">ocore-intg_ww@example.com</ns2:UsernameToken><ns3:PasswordText xmlns:ns3="http://tough.example.com/webservices">UiojdfdoiNN</ns3:PasswordText></ns1:Header>|0|620|null`

I just need the output in a separate file with date from the log file which is first column and email address, some thing like this

`2017-05-02 13:02:25 park.phannon23@example.com`

Can somebody help, I went through multiple sites but unable to format like above.

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. Please take a [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: *"I am pasting only one row from logfile"* But you have posted four lines of text, so it is impossible to guess what the original data looks like.

Comment: @Picard Everyone says that, but as you can see by the multiple answers below, as long as people are desperate for points, it clearly is.

Comment: @123: OP continues the same thing without tried anything no answers will be posted. I am damn sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = '[2017-05-02 13:02:25,986] [AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-10239] SID0003457|10.22.165.22|13|16|FAILED|500||<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Header><ns1:SessionType xmlns:ns1="http://tough.example.com/webservices">STATELESS</ns1:SessionType><ns2:UsernameToken xmlns:ns2="http://tough.example.com/webservices">ocore-intg_w
w@example.com</ns2:UsernameToken><ns3:PasswordText xmlns:ns3="http://tough.example.com/webservices">UdontsoiuN</ns3:PasswordText></S:Header><S:Body><getExternalPortalUserElement xmlns="http://ws.web.
tough1.tough.example.com/"><emailAddress>park.phannon23@example.com</emailAddress></getExternalPortalUserElement></S:Body></S:Envelope>|{http://ws.web.tough1.tough.example.com/}getExternalPortalUserElement|<n
s1:Header xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><ns1:SessionType xmlns:ns1="http://tough.example.com/webservices">STATELESS</ns1:SessionType><ns2:UsernameToken xmlns:ns2="http://tough.example.com/webservices">ocore-intg_ww@example.com</ns2:UsernameToken><ns3:PasswordText xmlns:ns3="http://tough.example.com/webservices">UiojdfdoiNN</ns3:PasswordText></ns1:Header>|0|620|null';

if ( $data =~ m!^\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*<emailAddress>([^<>]*)<\/emailAddress>!gs ){
    print "$1 $2 $3";   
}
```

Output: `2017-05-02 13:02:25 park.phannon23@example.com`

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/x6i61q)

Comment: `([^<>]*)` is preferable to `(.*)` in case there are two or more such elements in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use perl as follows

```
$ perl -ne '/\[(.*?)\].*\s+(\S+)\|\{/;print "$1  $2\n";' file1
2017-05-02 13:02:25,986  w@example.comUdontsoiuNpark.phannon23@example.com
```

Now with the edited example

```
perl -e 'undef $/;$content=<ARGV>;while($content=~/\[(.*?)\].*?<emailAddress>(.*)<\/emailAddress>/sg){print "$1  $2\n";}' file1
```

Comment: How is that useful when the OP asked for `2017-05-02 13:02:25 park.phannon23@example.com`?

Comment: @Borodin The question has changed, I didn't just invent some input did I?  Have a think about it!!

Comment: Version one of the question requires a result of `2017-05-02 13:02:25 park.phannon23@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to get the expected output:

```
my $date_email = "";
while(<DATA>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    $date_email .= "date = $1\t" if($line=~m/^\[([^\[\]]*)\]/m);
    $date_email .= "email = $1\n" if($line=~m/<emailAddress>([^<>]*)<\/emailAddress>/);

}

print $date_email;

__DATA__
[2017-05-02 13:02:25,986] [AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-10239] SID0003457|10.22.165.22|13|16|FAILED|500||<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Header><ns1:SessionType xmlns:ns1="http://tough.example.com/webservices">STATELESS</ns1:SessionType><ns2:UsernameToken xmlns:ns2="http://tough.example.com/webservices">ocore-intg_ww@example.com</ns2:UsernameToken><ns3:PasswordText xmlns:ns3="http://tough.example.com/webservices">UdontsoiuN</ns3:PasswordText></S:Header><S:Body><getExternalPortalUserElement xmlns="http://ws.web.tough1.tough.example.com/"><emailAddress>park.phannon23@example.com</emailAddress></getExternalPortalUserElement></S:Body></S:Envelope>|{http://ws.web.tough1.tough.example.com/}getExternalPortalUserElement|<ns1:Header xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><ns1:SessionType xmlns:ns1="http://tough.example.com/webservices">STATELESS</ns1:SessionType><ns2:UsernameToken xmlns:ns2="http://tough.example.com/webservices">ocore-intg_ww@example.com</ns2:UsernameToken><ns3:PasswordText xmlns:ns3="http://tough.example.com/webservices">UiojdfdoiNN</ns3:PasswordText></ns1:Header>|0|620|null
```

Output:

`date = 2017-05-02 13:02:25,986  email = park.phannon23@example.com`